# How to use \usepackage{hyperref} and \usepackage{chapterbib} together in the tex file?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, chapterbib

I wanted to have separate bibliography at the end of each chapter, So I used `\usepackage{chapterbib}`. So far everything is good. But when I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to my main.tex file, I get an error for each reference "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∕ (U+2215)" and all references appear at the end of all chapters. I don’t know how to fix this problem. I would like the pdf file to has the ability that once I click on the reference number, it jumps to that reference or when I click, for example, on the word "Fig.2" in the text, it jumps to that figure (I think `\usepackage{hyperref}` is responsible to activate this ability if I am not mistaken).

Here is my `main.tex` file

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}

\end{document}
```

And each `chapter.tex` is like:

```
\chapter{name of the chapter}
Some text and \ref{} and \label{} , and some \cite{} ....
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Comment: They do work together. You have to be more specific about "I get lots of errors" and "when I add `\usepackage{hyperref}`" and this `thesis` document class. Are you aware that hyperref likes to come after other packages?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau , thanks for your reply, I did not know that this package should be added at the end. The problem is solved now